# Rails 4 - How to get list of all companies from the "has_many -> belongs_to" relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, rails-activerecord, has-many

I have this structure of models:

```
class OrganizationBlast < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organization_blast_companies
end
class OrganizationBlastCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization_blast
  belongs_to :company
end
```

How do I get a list of all companies in a blast?
So far I am doing it this way:

```
organization_blast             = OrganizationBlast.find(params[:id])
organization_blast_companies   = organization_blast.organization_blast_companies.includes(:company)
organization_blast_companies.each do |organization_blast_company|
  puts organization_blast_company.company.name
  ...
```

I agree the naming conventions here are crazy.

However, is there a better way to obtain list of companies in the organization blast?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `has_many :through` association.

Set up Models as given below:

```
class OrganizationBlast < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organization_blast_companies
  has_many :companies, through: :organization_blast_companies
end
class OrganizationBlastCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization_blast
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organization_blast_companies
  has_many :organization_blasts, through: :organization_blast_companies
end
```

Then, just call `organisation_blast.companies` to fetch all companies associated with an OrganizationBlast object.

```
organization_blast = OrganizationBlast.find(params[:id])
organization_blast_companies = organization_blast.companies
```

Refer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Hope it helps :)